# Selecting Records in SQL using LIKE function to very specific avail

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I haven't been able to find a question that addressed an instance as specific as this, but apologies if I've missed something.

If I want to select records that contain a specific word **'Apple'**, but I want to ensure records that might contain the word **'PineApple'** are omitted, would the `LIKE` operator allow for this in this instance, or would there need to be further conditioning:

e.g

```
SELECT ID, Manufacturer FROM Table1 WHERE Manufacturer LIKE '%apple%'
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this using only `LIKE` and without regular expressions, you may try:

```sql
SELECT ID, Manufacturer
FROM Table1
WHERE Manufacturer LIKE 'apple %' OR    -- at the start of the name
      Manufacturer LIKE '% apple %' OR  -- in the middle
      Manufacturer LIKE '% apple';      -- at the end
```

Assuming your version of SQL does support some kind of regex like, you could match on the pattern `\bapple\b`, which means match `apple` as a standalone word.

Comment: So are you saying I'd need to apply all three WHERE clauses in unison to achieve the desired effect? Thank you for the answer, by the way.

Comment: So the logic here is that you only know that the manufacturer's name contains the standalone word `apple` if it surrounded on both sides by either spaces or the start/end of the entire name.  Yes, you need something like my answer, unless you can use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a space before and after the value, then you can search by `LIKE '% apple %'`

```
SELECT ID, Manufacturer 
FROM Table1 
WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(' ', Manufacturer, ' ')) LIKE '% apple %';
```

Comment: Thanks, so what is the effect of using your method here rather than mine?

Comment: @Velvetaura it was meant to solve your problem in a simpler manner than the other answer. However, I had a typo. You can test the query suggested in this answer now, as I have edited my answer and fixed the typo.